# What is gradient? What's the difference between gradient and divergence?

Tags: definition, differentiation, vector-fields, mathematics, calculus

I don't really get what's the difference between them. What does each thing physically and mathematically signify?
Aren't both things just a dot product with the del operator?

Comment: Taking the gradient of a scalar field produces a vector field, while divergence applied to a vector field produces a scalar field

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *Aren't both things just a dot product with the del operator?* No. The gradient doesn’t involve any dot product. It *can’t* because it only involves one “vectorial” thing — namely $\nabla$ — not two.